# How many chars can numeric EDIFACT data elements be long?

Tags: edi, edifact

In EDIFACT there are numeric data elements, specified e.g. as format n..5 -- we want to store those fields in a database table (with alphanumeric fields, so we can check them). How long must the db-fields be, so we can for sure store every possible valid value? I know it's at least two additional chars (for decimal point (or comma or whatever) and possibly a leading minus sign).

We are building our tables after the UN/EDIFACT standard we use in our message, not the specific guide involved, so we want to be able to store everything matching that standard. But documentation on the numeric data elements isn't really straightforward (or at least I could not find that part).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the information on the [UNECE web site](http://www.unece.org/) in the documentation on UN/EDIFACT rules [Part 4. UN/EDIFACT rules Chapter 2.2 Syntax Rules](http://www.unece.org/tradewelcome/areas-of-work/un-centre-for-trade-facilitation-and-e-business-uncefact/outputs/standards/unedifact/tradeedifactrules/part-4-edifact-rules-for-electronic-data-interchange-for-administration-commerce-and-transport/part-4-unedifact-rules-chapter-22-syntax-rules.html) . They don't say it directly, but when you put all the parts together, you get it. See TOC-entry 10: *REPRESENTATION OF NUMERIC DATA ELEMENT VALUES*.

Here's what it basically says:

*10.1: Decimal Mark* 
Decimal mark must be transmitted (if needed) as specified in UNA (comma or point, put always one character). It shall not be counted as a character of the value when computing the maximum field length of a data element.

*10.2: Triad Seperator* 
Triad separators shall not be used in interchange.

*10.3: Sign* 
[...] If a value is to be indicated to be negative, it shall in transmission be immediately preceded by a minus sign e.g. -112. The minus sign shall not be counted as a character of the value when computing the maximum field length of a data element. However, allowance has to be made for the character in transmission and reception.

To put it together: 
Other than the digits themselves there are only two (optional) chars allowed in a numeric field: the decimal seperator and a minus sign (no blanks are permitted in between any of the characters). These two extra chars are not counted against the maximum length of the value in the field.

So the maximum number of characters in a numeric field is the maximal length of the numeric field plus 2. If you want your database to be able to store every syntactically correct value transmitted in a field specified as `n..17`, your column would have to be 19 chars long (something like `varchar(19)`). Every EDIFACT-message that has a value longer than 19 chars in a field specified as `n..17` does not need to be stored in the DB for semantic checking, because it is already syntactically wrong and can be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

I used EDI Notepad from Liaison to solve a similar challenge.  https://liaison.com/products/integrate/edi/edi-notepad

I recommend anyone looking at EDI to at least get their free (express) version of EDI Notepad.

The "high end" version (EDI Notepad Productivity Suite) of their product comes with a "Dictionary Viewer" tool that you can export the min / max lengths of the elements, as well as type.  You can export the document to HTML from the Viewer tool. It would also handle ANSI X12 too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip -- but you need to register there (even for the free version), and I'm not about to do that with my company's information.

Comment: You could always fill it in with bogus information.  :)  It's just to get to the download page.  Once you fill out the form with a free email address, it'll let you download the software.  No need to speak with anyone there unless you want to.